# Calling 'firebase deploy' from PHP via shell_exec() doesn't work

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I'm trying to automate my deployment of hosting assets with Firebase using PHP.  I'm trying to call 'firebase deploy' using shell_exec() in PHP, but so far I cannot seem to get it to work.  No output is returned, and nothing gets written to a logfile if I pipe the output to one.

Is there any way to automate Firebase deployment using PHP?

(interesting note: since the 'firebase' command needs to be called from within the actual public directory that will be pushed, I'm guessing I need to call `'/usr/local/bin/firebase deploy'` and pass in the parameters of the Firebase directory that I want to push using the `-p` flag.  Is this correct or can I omit `-p` entirely?)

Firebase deploy works fine on the command line when I type it in manually.

Please help!

Comment: I think this has something to do with the user who is running the script?  I know you have to log in to the CLI for firebase to deploy files, maybe it has something to do with this?

Comment: So now I've a shell script that PHP calls, and I've even included the Firebase token in there and it deploys fine, writing output to a logfile.  But this shell script simply refuses to work when called from PHP.  Checked permissions, it is executable, etc.  Very frustrating.  What am I missing??  I can't believe this isn't documented anywhere.  Is nobody automating their firebase deployments out there?

Comment: not worked for me exec('PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH && firebase deploy --only hosting:sitename', $output);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Firebase, one of their awesome devs there helped me out and he suggested this, which worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
exec('PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH && firebase deploy', $output);
print_r($output);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

So thanks to Firebase support, I got this working.  It basically has to do with Apache and web sessions.  The $PATH was needed:

The problem has to do with the web server session. When running those commands, he found that the output is "command not found". This error is returned when the $PATH doesn't contain the path to the desired commands (in this case firebase and node).

To fix this, he had to add this path to $PATH in the current session, so it is possible to call 'firebase deploy'.

Thanks again, Firebase!

Comment: not worked for me exec('PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH && firebase deploy --only hosting:sitename', $output);